# Waiting for the user activities before proceeding to next step of code jquery

Tags: jquery

I am building simple plugin for confirmation. I am send request to plugin for `yes` or `no` activities. Click `yes` delete item from database & `no` escape the step. Now I want my plugin to wait for the user activity. If user click `no` then stop the current code of the function. If user press `yes` then proceed to remaining part of the code.

Like:

```
 $(document).on("click",".somebtn", function(){
      $(this).confirm();   //calls plugin

      $(this).confirm.no();  //calling plugin 'no' function
       // How to get returned data from this function of plugin
       //here I want my plugin to wait for user activity. 
       //If click 'no' then stop the code execution from here and 
       //if click 'yes' then go and execute code below.
      $(this).confirm.yes();

 });
```

Plugin

```
 jQuery.fn.confirm = function ()
 {
    jQuery.fn.confirm.yes = function (data)
     {
        //ajax calls
     };
    jQuery.fn.confirm.no = function ()
    {
       return "abcd";                 

    };
  };
```

Comment: You mean I need to share plugin code ??

Comment: I don't get it. Without user confirmation function won't go to the next step, so it works like it supposed to I think.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's gonna be helpful, but I created simple example with confirm window. http://jsfiddle.net/ws1zojqz/

Comment: Hi, Mike I had edited my question. I want to return `abcd` from plugin function and alert in code section. But Its not working for me.

Comment: I've added jsfiddle, isn't working for you ?

Comment: I don't want to use javascript alert. So I am bulding custom type.

Comment: What is expected result of `$(this).confirm.no();` followed by `$(this).confirm.yes();` at `click` event ?

Comment: Problem is that my object is still holding the previous `id` when I click `no` then after I click `yes`. All the `id` gets deleted including previous id that is store in object. So I want my data not to send to `$(this).confirm.yes();` function if user click `no`.

Answer (score 1):

**I've prepared an example for you with simple modal box.**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    //Show dialog Yes or No
    $('#proceed').on('click', function() {
         $('#dialog1').show();    
    });
             
    
     $.fn.confirm = function () {    
         return {
             yes: function () {        
                $('.answer').text('Clicked Yes');
                $('#dialog1').hide(); 
                 return "Yes"
     },
         no: function () {            
                $('.answer').text('Clicked No');
                $('#dialog1').hide(); 
               
             return "No"
     }
         }
     }
     
         $('#btn_yes').on('click', function() {
        $.fn.confirm().yes();
    });
    
    $('#btn_no').on('click', function() {
        $.fn.confirm().no();
    });
     
     
});
```

```css
body {
    padding:50px;
}
.popup {   
    display:none;
    width:300px;
    height:150px;
    padding:10px 20px;
    border:1px solid gray;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    
}

.proceed {
    margin: 30px;
}

.answer {
    margin-top: 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
    background: yellow;
    color: black;    
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="proceed">Show modal</button>

<div class="popup" id="dialog1">
    <p>Proceed to the next step?</p>
    <button id="btn_yes">Yes</button>
    <button id="btn_no">No</button>
</div>

<div class="answer">User answer</div>
```